# How to create a dynamically updating variable in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

what I'm trying to do is- I've a column in my excel workbook called "Banked Amount" which varies from month to month. Now, what I would like to do is to calculate a total of all the "Banked Amount" cells. Is there a formula that can do this automatically every month by picking up values from all previous month's banked amounts and putting a total on top of my workbook.

Note: As the year progresses, newer "banked amounts" cells are added to the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are stored in Column A, then your formula is:

> =SUM(A:A)

That sums the entire column (empty cells are zero).

Answer (score 1):

You can SUM the entire column as picobit indicates.

Or if you want the Total Amount to display in the top of the column, this won't do because it'll create a circular reference. So you'll need to SUM from the first row through whatever row count is sufficient to cover the maximum rows you would ever have. For example (if *Banked Amounts* are in column **H**, and the first value is in row **2**):

> SUM(H2:H2000)

Comment: Thanks Picobit and DeltaHotel for your input. I was able to get a total value using your method. I'm surprised that it works even though some of the columns contain non-numeric values. For e.g. I've "Banked amount" text in column A13, followed by it's numeric value in column B13. Next sequence is in column D13 and E13 respectively, and so on. So yeah, thanks for your input